# Zip multiple folders and files using powershell 2

Tags: file, powershell, zip, directory

I have the following structure of folders,subfolders and files inside each of them
C:\Prod\FolderName1
C:\Prod\FolderName1XX
C:\Prod\FolderName1YY
C:\Prod\FolderName1ZZ

I would like to have all Foldername1 folders with their subfolders and files zipped into a single zip file.

The following works fine with powershell 5.0

```
$name = Read-Host 'enter the folder NAME'
$namexx = $name + 'xx'
$nameyy = $name + 'yy'
$namezz = $name + 'zz'

$fullpath = join-path -path 'C:\Prod\' -childpath $name
$fullpathxx = join-path -path 'C:\Prod\' -childpath $namexx
$fullpathyy = join-path -path 'C:\Prod\' -childpath $nameyy
$fullpathzz = join-path -path 'C:\Prod\' -childpath $namezz

Compress-Archive -LiteralPath $fullpath,$fullpathxx,$fullpathyy,$fullpathzz -CompressionLevel Optimal -DestinationPath "C:\Dev\$blue $(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd).zip"
```

Unfortunately on the server where it has to happen the Powershell is version 2.0 and does not have the Compress-Archive cmdlet.

I tried

```
Add-Type -Assembly "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem" ;
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory("$fullpath", "c:\dev\$name.zip") ;
```

but this approach creates multiple zip files for each of the folders.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a command-line zip tool.

Comment: I'm not seeing a question here, unless it's an implicit "will someone write Compress-Archive for me for PS v2?", which I'd say is too broad. Upgrade the server to PowerShell 5. Use a remote computer with PS 5 and a file share to get to the files. Use [7-zip](https://www.7-zip.org).

Comment: The question is a matter of interpretation. For you might be "will someone write Compress-Archive for me for PS v2?" for other will be "how to zip up multiple folders into a single zip file?"
Upgrading 200 servers with powershell 5 is not a very viable solution, unless you were joking with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to do this in 2.0 using the DotNetZip library.

> You can find all the documentation/downloads you will need here:
>  <strike>https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=dotnetzip</strike>
>
> https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetZip/
>
> https://github.com/haf/DotNetZip.Semverd

To implement it into a PS script, you'll want to do something like this:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("your \ path \ to \ the \ dll \ file") 

#To zip a file, do this: 
$zipObj = New-Object Ionic.Zip.Zipfile
$zipObj.AddFile($fileName, "file")
$zipObj.Save($saveFileName)
$zipObj.Dispose()

#To zip a directory, do this:
$zipObj = New-Object Ionic.Zip.Zipfile
$zipObj.AddDirectory($directoryName,"dir")
$zipObj.Save($saveDirectoryName)
$zipObj.Dispose()
```

Hope this helps! I know it's a pain having to depend on another tool - but this dll has really done wonders (and we continue to use it even though Powershell 4 is capable of zipping on it's own).

> There is another good example here (with encryption):
> https://documentation.help/DotNetZip/Powershell.htm

EDIT: Codeplex is being taken down soon, and I hate when I click on a link that has been shutdown, so if anyone in the future is looking for this library, you can find it here:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetZip/

https://github.com/haf/DotNetZip.Semverd